# Performing denial of service attack using Python

Tags: penetration-test, server, buffer-overflow, python, client

I am a student so please don't be rude for I miss something and this project is for research purpose only.

I am willing to perform a denial of service attack(on my own servers) I am not willing to do the script kiddie method of downloading and running some online codes I have programmed my own servers and clients here is the client which sends buffers thereby overflowing the buffers

```
class BufferOverflow:
def overflow(self,host,port):
    id = 0
    while True:
        print("================================================================")
        try:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            print("[*] NetWorker Report: Sockets have been created against the server")
        except socket.error:
            print("[*] Adim permission required or port in use")
        buffer = "\x4e"*3000
        print("[*] Connecting to %s on %d"%(host,port))
        client.connect((host,port))
        print("[*] Connection established")
        exploit_packet = ("USV "+buffer+"//n//r//r").encode("UTF-8")
        print("[*] Initializing...")
        client.send(exploit_packet)
        print("[*] Initialized!")
        print("[*] Restarting...")
        client.close()
        print("[*] Restarted!")
        print("[*] Session ID: %d"%id)
        id+=1
```

This sends buffers to the server with the desired it, I have implemented my own sniffer which could resolve DNS to I.P so that I can get the I.P.

Here is the code to my own custom servers implementation,
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144661/penetration-testing-in-an-unsuitable-environment

I used a basic TCP server from my code on code review on it to test,
[image]

In the screen shot the top left most is the server which displays the buffer like "NNN....3000*N" = > single buffer which is sent by the client, I used multiple clients to overblown the buffer. Finally I got success the top right most one which displayed this message,
[image]

Win 10061 error is nothing but the server has stopped or inactive. I know that the service is available for the present clients which I have created, so I have opened  a new power shell along with the running clients and connected to the server but the server still responds , I don't know why?

Am I missing something or this is not actually the correct implementation of denial of service attack?

I am a student and I am willing to learn from you please do not be rude I have misunderstood some concepts and provided a wrong implementation

Comment: What is your question? What is the outcome you were expecting?

Comment: While your program is used in the context of information security the problem you face is actually a programming question, i.e. off-topic here and on-topic on stackoverflow.com. What would be on-topic here are the concepts of how to do such thing but not the debugging of your program. But the concepts are mainly missing from your question.

Comment: @schroeder, My question is to know whether I am performing denial of service attack in the right manner or there is any thing missing?

Comment: If your service becomes unavailable, then your DoS worked... It's unclear in your question whether you think you were successful or not ...

Comment: It's a horrible implementation of DoS. This is fundamentally different from how DoS works in the real world. Nowadays DoS is done with amplification and is always distributed. Also you have to spoof IPs. And the packets should really not be named exploit, nothing gets exploited here.

Comment: @AdHominem that's DDoS ... and you do NOT have to spoof IPs. DoS is perfectly valid even if it only takes a single packet from a single source.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I dont know why you came to this assumption, I am cautious I know there is not a bug in my code I am just asking whether I am performing the dos attack in right manner, what is missing to overflow the server(I am not demanding any code) I ask for opinions and Ideas how effectively overflow the server and what I am missing, there is noting stack overflow can do with this

Comment: @schroeder I just said it's a bad implementation.

Comment: @schroeder, yes the service becomes unavailable when error 10061 occurs one the last client, I just ran another terminal and made a connection with a new client, If it is a successful DOS attack then the service should be denied for further clients but it doesn't I dont know why?

Comment: @AdHominem actually you said a lot more than that and pretty much every statement you made in that comment is wrong on the facts.

Comment: @VISWESWARAN1998: I recommend you describe how you want to do the attack first so one can check if the idea is right. There are several ways to do DOS so please don't expect all to look at your code to figure out what you are trying to do and then check if the code actually does what you try to do. Again: show the concepts and not the code.

Comment: @VISWESWARAN1998 then what you are asking for is a code review of both your service and your attack. We don't do that here. There are lots of reasons why your service would die then be available again, including threading or the service restarting itself. Ultimately, this is a code question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I use TCP floods to overflow the buffer, it sends buffers to the server

Comment: @schroeder, I am Neither asking to debug my code nor demanded some code or asked you to debug my code, from the beginning I am asking what is the best ways to perform DOS attack so that "I" can implement on my code! that's all this is a pure information security question to my knowledge

Comment: @VISWESWARAN1998 you might not know it, but you are asking us to debug your code. To cause a service to fail, it must have a design vulnerability of some sort. There are numerous types of vulnerabilities that can cause a DoS. By giving us your *client* code, you are asking about your specific implementation. What I suggest is that you focus on the server code, not the client or the runtime errors. But once you do that, then it becomes a specific code design review, which brings us back to a debug question.

Comment: If you want to learn, I suggest looking at known DoS vulnerabilities in other server code. Then write a client to DoS the particular vulnerability. Then work on designing your own design vulnerabilities.

Comment: @schroeder Oh I see from your comment I understand that DOS attacks are specific to servers and implementation of client for wide range of servers is useless rather waste of time since different servers may have different vulnerabilities, instead one should exploit the vulnerabilities of target server and then design the client according to it? is this what you say?

Comment: @VISWESWARAN1998 that's exactly what I'm saying. If you want to kill any type of service, then you need to flood it with so much traffic that the network the server is on gets too full to operate. Then you need a great deal of clients, and enormous amounts of traffic. But for a single client to kill a single service, you need to exploit a resource vulnerability in that service.

Comment: @schroeder Thank you your comment should be posted as an answer so that I can accept it thereby saving others time(since they read all and finally know it is solved!)